# Open a bootstrap modal (on the page it exists on) from an external page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

There are many questions about loading a modal from another page on the current page, or opening a modal on the current page on page load.

What I would like to do (I acknowledge it is slightly unorthodox UI) is to click on an image hotspot (an individual within a team photo) on /home, which opens /team#modal1.
Simply targeting the modal with a link will not cause it to open.

I could replicate the modal content on /home, but this would possibly be more confusing to the user, as the /team page already contains all of these headshots and modal details for each member. If someone is interested in learning more about team members, they will then be on the right page to discover more, and content is not duplicated.

I did not find anything in the Bootstrap4 documentation about this, except that the remote path option has been depracated in v4:

`<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>`

To be clear, I do not want to open a modal from another page on the current page.
I want to click on a link that opens another page, and opens a specific modal on that page without further clicks.

Is there a way to do this natively in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery 1.9 or above you could use the [target selector](https://api.jquery.com/target-selector/) to select the modal and then use `.modal('show')` in your document ready function to display the modal.  So basically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(":target").modal("show")
});
```

However, you should be aware of the possibly security implications (e.g. XSS) of using this approach.  For example, take
a look at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177261/is-xss-possible-with-jquerylocation-hash

Comment: How does this address linking to the modal from a separate page? How exactly would you write the link from /home to /team#modal (open)